# Unable to get a list of updates: remote lvfs has no cache signature

Tags: software-center, gnome-software, fwupd

Ubuntu Software (aka Gnome Software) on Ubuntu 18.04 has started giving the error message:
*Unable to get a list of updates: remote lvfs has no cache signature*

[image: Ubuntu Software error message]

This issue started recently and, based on a bit of online research, it may be related to [Linux Vendor Firmware Service (LVFS) and the **fwupd** application](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/docs/users).

Here are the installed fwupd packages:

```
~$ apt list --installed | grep fwupd
fwupd/bionic-updates,now 1.2.10-1ubuntu2~ubuntu18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
fwupd-signed/bionic-updates,now 1.10~ubuntu18.04.3+1.2.10-1ubuntu2~ubuntu18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fwupdate/bionic-updates,now 12-7~ubuntu18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
fwupdate-signed/bionic-updates,now 12-7~ubuntu18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
libfwupd2/bionic-updates,now 1.2.10-1ubuntu2~ubuntu18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

and

```
~$ snap list | grep fwupd
fwupd 1.4.2 2084  latest/stable    richard-hughes  classic
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update 22-Oct-2020**: From the discussions below it seems like this warning pops up for a few people for `fwupd` versions from 1.3.x, so this issue may not be directly due to whether `fwupd` is installed via snap or apt. Instead, it may be due a combination of having a 1.3.x+ version of `fwupd` and using a specific device/vendor.

---

I believe I found the answer after a bit of trial and error. I seem to have both the snap and apt versions of fwupd installed. Removing the fwupd snap version seems to fix the warning message:

```
snap remove fwupd
```

However, I don't believe this warning is causing any problems as it seems to be due to misconfiguration on the firmware vendor side. At worst, this warning means that you won't get firmware updates automatically for the affected devices.

My snap `fwupd` version number (1.4.2) was newer than apt version number (1.2.10), so I decided to just keep the snap version and ignore the warning message.

Comment: This command returned: snap "fwupd" is not installed. So did not fix for me. Running Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: @VadimH , I wonder if this issue is related to the fwupd version. Which version of fwupd do you have installed? Use `apt list --installed | grep fwupd`.

Comment: @JayDin I have 
`fwupd-signed/focal-updates,now 1.27.1ubuntu2+1.3.11-1~focal1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`; 
`fwupd/focal-updates,now 1.3.11-1~focal1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`; 
`libfwupd2/focal-updates,now 1.3.11-1~focal1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`; 
`libfwupdplugin1/focal-updates,now 1.3.11-1~focal1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat - I have added an update to the answer. I suspect this warning is due a specific device/vendor. If it's of interest, I can start a chat so that we can try to find the culprit by comparing our devices.

Comment: @JayDin Thanks, the issue not worth it. Maybe it is related to the fact that I manually installed latest Linux kernel.

Comment: @JayDin Yes, I have the same versions as 4LegsDrivenCat

Comment: The warning no longer appears after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat - what is the fwupd version in Ubuntu 20.10? Is it a snap or apt install?

Comment: @JayDin `snap list | grep fwupd` returns nothing, `apt list --installed | grep fwupd` returns  `fwupd-signed/groovy,now 1.30+1.4.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fwupd/groovy,now 1.4.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfwupd2/groovy,now 1.4.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfwupdplugin1/groovy,now 1.4.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`

Comment: Thanks @4LegsDrivenCat -  hopefully that means that this warning is fixed from fwupd  version 1.4.5-1 onward.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04. No snap fwupd. Apt version of fwupd: `fwupd-signed/focal-updates,now 1.27.1ubuntu2+1.3.11-1~focal1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fwupd/focal-updates,now 1.3.11-1~focal1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfwupd2/focal-updates,now 1.3.11-1~focal1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfwupdplugin1/focal-updates,now 1.3.11-1~focal1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`

Comment: @JayDin I've encountered this on Ubuntu 20.04. I have NO devices that could have updated firm (in fact I reproduced this in KVM virtualised). There is no fwupd snap installed in 20.04 LTS - just the apt system version. The problem seems to be the snap-store UI: in a fresh install of 20.04, fully updated via apt but with NO updates to snaps, it is fine. Updating "snap-store" (preinstalled) from version "3.36.0-80-g208fd61" to version "3.36.0-82-g80486d0" causes the problem. Why is the snap store UI trying to get a list of firmware updates? Does the UI have a bug in how it invokes the tool?

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and try this command

```
fwupdmgr --force refresh
```

From [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/fwupdmgr.1.html):

> `--force`
> Force the action by relaxing some runtime checks
>
> `refresh [FILE FILE_SIG REMOTE-ID]`
> Refresh metadata from remote server

Comment: The command did the trick, I also changed my BIOS settings, it was configured to boot to LEGACY first, now it boots to UEFI first. The error message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably somehow disabled, so you have to enable it using:

```
sudo fwupdmgr enable-remote lvfs
```

[Related documentation](https://lvfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/offline.html).

Comment: Entering the above command (command result: `Successfully enabled remote`) did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is listed as a supported device I recommend following the instructions here https://support.starlabs.systems/kb/updates/installing-updates-from-the-lvfs and install the GUI which will enable you to keep track and update your device's firmware. Going through these steps seemed to fix my issues.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1187507)

Comment: I tried to open the link and got this error message " You are attempting to read an article that is only accessible to verified staff users. Please login here to view. Contact your Admin if you cannot view after logging in." 
Can you please post the full text from the link.