# Integrity: problem loading X.509 certificate -65 before login

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, lenovo, bios, certificates

I was able to clean any error displayed before log into Ubuntu 20.04.1.
I am using the newest Kernel  version 5.9.1 , because my Lenovo had issues with graphic drivers at actual stable version.

I am using dual boot and I have only 1 SSD disk.

Displayed info/error are at picture below:

[image]

Comment: Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243361/931617).

Comment: Snap fwupd is not installed. Not works.

Comment: You can also keep secure boot by signing the kernel thats what I'm trying to learn.
useful link https://gloveboxes.github.io/Ubuntu-for-Azure-Developers/docs/signing-kernel-for-secure-boot.html this link got me through it. its pretty easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this message into my laptop BIOS. All you need to do is:

1. Disable the Secure Boot
2. Reset Setup Mode. This function is in BIOS.

After that, just exit BIOS and save changes.

Comment: This doesn't fix the root of the issue, just disable the whole thing